# Python `print` passing extra text to sys.stdout?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, sys

This is probably something stupid I am missing but it has really got me hung up on a larger project (`c` extension) that I am writing.

Why is `print "Hello, World!"` passing `None` and an extra `\n` to `sys.stdout` here?

```
>>> import sys
>>> class StdOutHook:
...     def write(self, text):
...         sys.__stdout__.write("stdout hook received text: %s\n" % repr(text))
... 
>>> class StdErrHook:
...     def write(self, text):
...         sys.__stderr__.write("stderr hook received text: %s\n" % repr(text))
... 
>>> sys.stdout = StdOutHook()
>>> sys.stderr = StdErrHook()
>>> 
>>> def x():
...     print "Hello, World!"
... 
>>> 
>>> print x()
stdout hook received text: 'Hello, World!'
stdout hook received text: '\n'
stdout hook received text: 'None'
stdout hook received text: '\n'
>>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print x()` prints the return value of `x()` which is implicitly `None`

Either replace `print "Hello world"` with `return "Hello world"` or replace `print x()` with `x()`

Comment: OMG, I just realized my `def x()` is printing, not returning.... I am an idiot..  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

First, print automatically adds a new line unless you specify otherwise. If you don't want a new line add a comma:

```
print "Hello, World!",
```

Second, you are printing the return of the x() function which is None. The function `f()` is equivalent to this:

```
def x():
    print "Hello, World!"
    return None
```

So `print x()` prints `None`.

Comment: Thank you!  This was dumb of me... I should be returning the "Hello, World!" not printing it.  Problem solved =).

Answer (score 1):

```
def x():
   print "Hello, World!"
```

Will execute `print` and return `None` - additional newlines are generated by `print` and `None` is printed since you wrote `print x()` :)

If you wish to eliminate the additional newline, write `x` instead as:

```
def x():
   sys.stdout.write("Hello, World!")
```